# React Native react-native-sound Changing Sound file at run time gives error "Attempted to assign to readonly property"

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I am new to React-Native. And am trying to develop an Audio App, where the user should be able to click on any Audio from a list, and that Audio should Play onPress()

Here is my code

```
sound = new Sound('http://example.com/xyz.mp3');

playSound ()  {
    this.sound.play();
};

pauseSound () {
    this.sound.pause();
};

playFile (x1) {

    sound = new Sound(x1);
    this.playSound();

}
```

When I call playFile(x1) with a new file name x1, it gives error:

```
Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

Is there a wayto reassign a new value to the **sound** variable onPress? Or any other simple solution to this issue of reassignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself.

if you use sound.release() before assigning a new file, it works.

It allows you to re-assign a new file. Hence the code will be like this:

```
sound.release();
sound = new Sound(x1);
```